# Trying to make a Chrome App (packaged)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

So I'm trying to create a packaged Chrome App,so far I have gotten the app to install properly and show some static text and a picture, however I cannot for the life of me get any JavaScript to the work inside the window.html file. I know that they are certain API's that Google provides but it seems like absolutely nothing is running. Has anyone else had this issue or does anyone have the answer to making an app that does something?

Sam

EDIT

manifest.json

```
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "description": "Test application",
      "version": "0.1",
      "app": {
        "background": {
          "scripts": ["background.js"]
        }
      },
      "icons": {"128": "icon.png"},
    "permissions": ["storage"]
    }
```

window.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function test(){
            alert("Hello there!");
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border ="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img border='0' src='icon.png'></td>
                    <td><b>Test</b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button onclick='test();'>Store</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add your `manifest.json` file and `window.html` code. Have you tried to debug your app?

Comment: Added request code. I had a look around as far as I could the debugger feature was removed from Chrome for some reason, open to suggestions though.

Comment: Figured it out, something to do with content secuirty policy.

Comment: If you've figured it out, please post your answer to your own question so that others in the same situation can help themselves. This is a community site, not a tech-support board!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, basically Chrome Apps do not allow any inline scripts to be run. So what you must do is create separate script files and include action listeners. More information in the [link here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Comment: As I've just posted on a different bug, when you're developing Chrome apps, using the console is imperative (both the background page and foreground page ones) - it often provides very useful feedback on what's going on. In your case, an error message about violating the Content Security Policy was printed there.

Comment: Also, [Chrome App Samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples) on GitHub is a quick way to learn how certain things are done and/or get a primer app going in order to gradually transform it to whatever you need to do.